# IE8: weird border around HTML button element

Tags: html, css, button, internet-explorer-8

I have a button element with a custom background (image+color) and no borders except for a 2px border-bottom (and a bunch of other properties --code below) which renders quite differently in Firefox and in IE8. The problem is, this is a work for a company that uses IE8 as their only browser, so it's important that the button renders well in IE8.

Here's a visual comparison between the two:

[image: comparison FF/IE8]

My question here is *not* about the padding difference (I'm looking into that), but about the weird border that is visible on IE8 *in addition* to the regular border (border-bottom).

Can anyone explain to me where it comes from and how to get rid of it?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<button class="btn" id="c_edit">
    <span>Annuler</span>
</button>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 7px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: FrutigerLTStd55Roman, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;  
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
    background-color: #999;
    background-image: url('img/btn_bg.gif');
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.btn span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 10px 6px 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: 4px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Wait. What is this supposed to do? `border-bottom: 2px solid #222;`

Comment: Can you confirm the doctype you're using. Also check what rendering mode IE8 is using -- use F12 to open the dev tools to check this.

Comment: Also, are you using any kind of CSS reset or normaliser?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos: it's supposed to add a two pixels border bottom. You can see that on the images (although barely since the background is quite dark itself). I have similar buttons in other colors where it is more visible.

Comment: @Spudley: the doctype is a standard HTML5 doctype. No CSS reset or normalizer. As for the rendering mode, unfortunately I don't have access to my client's computer at the time being (the picture above is from a screenshot he sent me) but I'll keep that in mind next time I get to ask him. Could you maybe already expand about that topic? What are some possible cases and available fixes?

Comment: Any time I see dramatically different rendering in IE vs other browsers, the first thing I check is the browser mode. You'd be surprised how often that's the problem. Both quirks mode and compatibility mode can be problematic, but quirks mode more so. Typically if you have a doctype, that normally deals with the quirks mode issue, but there are still ways for it to sneak past, so it's still worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser renders text differently, since you have not set the `height` but only `font-size`, the height of the button will differ depending on OS and rendering engine of that browser.

To fix this give the button the same `height` as the image, or smaller if you want to crop it.

Comment: If possible - could you provide us a jsFiddle to play around with? We can then link you an updated version that will fix your problem.